# RequiredFieldValidator with RadNumericTextBox

Tags: requiredfieldvalidator

When I combine a RadNumericTextBox with RequiredFieldValidator with a mask of "<0..99>:<0..59>:<0..59>" I don't get the error message when nothing is entered, because by default "00:00:00" is saved. How can I prevent from the text box assuming that "00:00:00" is a legitimate value.

Comment: That is a RadMaskedTextBox and not RadNumericTextBox. I gave Mask as "##:##:##" and DisplayMask as "<0..99>:<0..59>:<0..59>".

Comment: <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox runat="server" ID="RadMaskedTextBox1" DisplayMask="<0..99>:<0..59>:<0..59>" Mask="##:##:##"></telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
     
</telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Not Entered!" ControlToValidate="RadMaskedTextBox1" runat="server"/>
 
<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" />

Comment: But now the value passed is the display mask. For instance, if I type 00:12:42, it is sent as 00:59:59. Why is that?